# "No module named error" when try to run Elasticalert

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

When I try to run elastalert

```
python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --start 2019-09-04 --rule rules/rule.yaml --config config.yaml
```

I get following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elastalert-0.2.1-py2.7.egg/elastalert/elastalert.py", line 29, in <module>
    from . import kibana
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elastalert-0.2.1-py2.7.egg/elastalert/kibana.py", line 4, in <module>
    import urllib.error
ImportError: No module named error
```

My environment is 
ubuntu 18 
elasticsearch 6.3.0